# is there an add attribution function that returns the object

Tags: r

```
add_text=function(x, t) {
  attr(x, 'text') = t
  return(x)
}
```

I can define the above function add one attribute to an object and return the changed object back. But this is specific to a particular attribute.

How to define a function so that it can be called in the following way?

```
add_attr(x, a1='v1', a2='v2') # return an object with attr a1 and a2, whose values are v1 and v2 respectly.
```

This is just an example. You can put an arbitrary number of attributes and their values in the argument. Also, is there a native R that does this already (I don't find it)?

Comment: `structure`.....

Comment: What do you want to happen if `x` already has some attributes with names other than `a1` or `a2`?  @AllanCameron's solution will delete them, mine and @akrun's will keep them.  All three solutions will overwrite existing attributes already named `a1` or `a2`.

Comment: They should leave as is.

Comment: That's what @rawr's suggestion `structure()` does.

Answer (score 4):

The following function should give you the desired behaviour:

```r
add_attr <- function(...)
{
  new_attr <- as.list(match.call())[-(1:2)]
  x <- eval(match.call()[[2]], parent.frame())
  attributes(x) <- new_attr
  return(x)
}
```

For example:

```
x <- 1

add_attr(x, a1='v1', a2='v2')
#> [1] 1
#> attr(,"a1")
#> [1] "v1"
#> attr(,"a2")
#> [1] "v2"
```

Though it's probably easier and more idiomatic to do:

```r
x <- 1
attributes(x) <- list(a1='v1', a2='v2')

x
#> [1] 1
#> attr(,"a1")
#> [1] "v1"
#> attr(,"a2")
#> [1] "v2"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

As @rawr said in a comment, this is what `structure` does:

```r
x <- 1
x <- structure(x, a1='v1', a2='v2')
y <- structure(x, a3='v3')
x
#> [1] 1
#> attr(,"a1")
#> [1] "v1"
#> attr(,"a2")
#> [1] "v2"
y
#> [1] 1
#> attr(,"a1")
#> [1] "v1"
#> attr(,"a2")
#> [1] "v2"
#> attr(,"a3")
#> [1] "v3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @AllanCameron's function, we could use @rawr's `structure` within `do.call`

```
add_attr <- function(...) {
    do.call(structure, list(...))

}
```

-testing

```
x <- 1
x1 <- add_attr(x, a1='v1', a2='v2')
add_attr(x1, a3 = 'v3')
```